# How do I drop multiple columns from a VIEW in Oracle SQL developer for good

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So the script that I have used for creating the view is as follows:

```
create view Grantson_Samples as  
(  
  select *  
  from MEASUREMENT  
  inner join SCIENTIST using (Scientist_Num)  
  inner join SITE using (Site_ID)  
  inner join MEASUREMENT_TYPE using (Name)  
  where SCIENTIST_NUM = '31415'  
  );
```

Don't worry about the stuff in caps (those are other tables). The problem however is that the view generated has all these extra columns that I don't want. How do I drop those?
Essentially everything in the red box needs to go.

Thanks and apologies in advance for any mistakes made. Rookie SQL learner here.

[image: Screenshot of the view.]

This is all in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Quite simple: don't use the dreaded `select *` (btw: the parentheses around the select are useless)

Answer (score 1):

Decide on what columns you want to keep.  Then:

```
create or replace view Grantson_Samples as
    select col1, col2, . . .
    from MEASUREMENT inner join
         SCIENTIST
         using (Scientist_Num) inner join
         SITE
         using (Site_ID) inner join
         MEASUREMENT_TYPE
         using (Name)
    where SCIENTIST_NUM = '31415';
```

Basically, this recreates the view with the columns that you want.

Comment: This is the answer.  The only other thing that I would suggest is that it might make more sense to drop and recreate the view, depending on the situation.